# Two different Private Keys

Tags: java, x509certificate, keystore, private-key

I am trying to digitally sign and then validate an AuthnRequest.
I've generated the private key and public key certificate using the following commands:

```
openssl genrsa -out privatekey.pem 2048
openssl req -new -x509 -key privatekey.pem -out publickey.cer -days 365
openssl pkcs12 -export -out public_privatekey.pfx -inkey privatekey.pem -in publickey.cer
```

Converted the PFX to JKS by following command:

```
keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore public_privatekey.pfx -srcstoretype pkcs12 
-destkeystore clientcert.jks -deststoretype JKS
```

and I am accessing that private key entry and public key certificate using the following java code:

```
KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("JKS");
ks.load(new FileInputStream(keystoreFile), "dps123!@#".toCharArray());

KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry keyEntry = (KeyStore.PrivateKeyEntry) ks.getEntry("1", new KeyStore.PasswordProtection("dps123!@#".toCharArray()));
java.security.cert.X509Certificate cert = (java.security.cert.X509Certificate) keyEntry.getCertificate();
```

I got to print the private key value to the console by following:

```
String key = Base64.encode(keyEntry.getPrivateKey().getEncoded());
System.out.println(key);
```

When I compare the contents of String "key" and the contents in "privatekey.pem" file, both are different. Is it something that I am not understanding correctly or there is a problem getting the private key value in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are several formats for private key storage. Among them are [PKCS#1](http://tools.ietf.org/rfc/rfc3447.txt) and [PKCS#8](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc5208.txt). They differ in encryption algorithms and ASN.1 structure. Also, PKCS#8 supports other key algorithms besides RSA.

For example this is the ASN.1 dump of the first bytes of an unencrypted PKCS#8 file:

```
0000  4BE: SEQUENCE {
0004    1:   INTEGER 0
0007    D:   SEQUENCE {
0009    9:     OBJECT IDENTIFIER rsaEncryption (1 2 840 113549 1 1 1)
         :       (PKCS #1)
0014    0:     NULL
         :     }
0016  4A8:   OCTET STRING, encapsulates {
001A  4A4:     SEQUENCE {
001E    1:       INTEGER 0
0021  101:       INTEGER    
         :         00 B3 17 E6 31 3C 36 24    ....1<6$
```

And the same key in PKCS#1 format (again only the first few bytes, the rest of the file is basically the raw key):

```
0000  4A4: SEQUENCE {
0004    1:   INTEGER 0
0007  101:   INTEGER    
         :     00 B3 17 E6 31 3C 36 24    ....1<6$
```

This website contains a more detailed explanation of the two formats:
https://tls.mbed.org/kb/cryptography/asn1-key-structures-in-der-and-pem

Java normally generates PKCS#8 format, while OpenSSL supports both formats and can convert between them: https://www.openssl.org/docs/apps/pkcs8.html

[KeyStore Explorer](http://keystore-explorer.sourceforge.net/) can also generate, process and convert both formats.

So, if you convert `privatekey.pem` to PKCS#8 with OpenSSL or KSE, it should look identical to the output of `System.out.println(key)`:

```
openssl pkcs8 -topk8 -in privatekey.pem -out privatekey.pkcs8 -nocrypt
```

Comment: oh yes, I ran the command you mentioned and the private key contents are now identical. Is this mean that the private key is different with PKCS#1 and PKCS#8, or the key remains the same and it is just format for private key storage?

Comment: @MuhammadSalmanFarooq The key itself does not change, PKCS#1 and #8 are just different storage formats.

Comment: @Omikron Hi, I got a base64 encoded string of RSA public key, and how can I know it's  PKCS#1 or PKCS# fromat in java? Actually, I got both of the format string, and I can decode it into java RSApublickey object with with diffrent method, and I want to determine which format in one method and do the translate~

Answer (score 1):

It's a bit difficult to say what kind of encoding will your java provider use. Also, when you compare with "privatekey.pem" file, how do you get content?

I don't have a direct solution but some suggestions below:

print out your pem

```
> openssl -in privatekey.pem -outform <DER/PEM>
```

Somewhere in the print will be base64 encoded private key.

Also, try checking your JCE provider which encoding it uses.

Comment: I've opened the privatekey.pem file in text-editor. It have contents like "-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- <privateKey> -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"

Comment: in your text editor what shows in the place of <privateKey>, does it look like MIIEuwIBADANBgkqhkiG9w0BAQEF.........o25O4os=====

Comment: Yes exactly it looks like this. But here is the question, the value you are talking about is different in the .pem file with the one I loaded from Java code. I've load it from the same keystore and keyentery.

Comment: how about printing out in DER and PEM format with openssl? does it produce a different output?
It will also help to printout using keytool itself. 
keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks. 
java may use a different encoding from your pem file. It depends on your JCE provider

Answer (score 0):

```
String key = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(keyEntry.getPrivateKey().getEncoded());
```

Comment: It does the same thing as "Base64.encode(keyEntry.getPrivateKey().getEncoded())" is doing for me.